# US App Developer Patent Troll Avoidance Checklist — Publishing as individual vs as Company

Tags: patent-infringement, app

I am working on a checklist (or list or strategies to consider) for new *individual* developers residing in the US who are about to release their first app, but are worried about patent trolls.

Whether publish the app as an Individual -- "SuperCalc by Earnest 'you wouldn't go so low as sue me, right?' Shmoe" vs as a company (eg., LLC) -- "SuperCalc by Come Sue My Impersonal Pants Off, Please, LCC" ... that is the question for today:

Since there appears to be no precedent for a Patent Troll suing an individual developer (that has published as an individual/sole proprietor *under their personal name*), could it be argued that it is actually safer to do that than to form an LLC?

Comment: An LLC is a useful tool to protect family wealth in case of a law suit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing correlation and causation here.

If there's no precedent for trolls suing individual developers then that's because most people create a company when their app becomes big.

I don't think anyone will not sue you just because you are an individual instead of a company if they think you're infringing their patent and they can make good money by it.